# WSO2: Dashboard Issues and Personalization

Tags: legend, scatter-plot, dashboard, wso2-cep

I am using wso2cep dashboard for displaying network traffic related information by exploiting various graphs. I was wondering if there is any way I can customize legend for each type of graph or set it globally as its create confusion for the viewer, elaborated in screen shot.

In piechart others = blue

In dest port vs src ip other = orange

One thing more
Scatter plot is shifted to left side of the window cutting ips on the y-axis and there is a space left on right side which can be used.
How can I drag the chart towards right side?

[image: Legend customization and placement of charts]

And also scatter chart is not rendering multiple y-axis values against single x-axis value. Here is the screen shot for that and values against it is plotted.

source_ip, source_port, destination_ip, destination_port, protocol
192.168.227.102,123,192.168.227.101,21,ftp
192.168.227.102,101,192.168.227.101,21,ftp
192.168.227.105,445,192.168.227.101,21,ftp
192.168.227.105,123,192.168.227.101,21,ftp
192.168.227.105,65576,192.168.227.101,22,ssh
192.168.227.109,123,192.168.227.101,22,ssh
192.168.227.109,123,192.168.227.101,22,ssh
192.168.227.109,3345,192.168.227.101,22,ssh
192.168.227.233,123,192.168.227.101,445,smb
192.168.227.233,123,192.168.227.101,445,smb
192.168.227.233,111,192.168.227.101,445,smb
192.168.227.202,123,192.168.227.101,3302,smtp
192.168.227.202,233,192.168.227.101,3302,smtp
192.168.227.102,123,192.168.227.101,3302,smtp
192.168.227.102,123,192.168.227.101,25,sql
192.168.227.102,123,192.168.227.101,25,sql

[image: scatter chart missing values]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because generated gadgets are deciding the the color scale and domain dynamically based on the data that has been passed to chart.

If you want to explicitly specify the color domain and color scale you can configure those in generated gadgets by modifying the VizGrammar (which is the chart library used) configuration of the charts.

This can be done by changing chart api js file, there will be a config creation like this [1] and there add colorDomain for you predefined options like below. Then the domain will be defined statically without dynamically changing the order and the colors has to be constant

```
conf.colorDomain = ["MySQL","SMB","OTHER"]
```

Even you can define your own colors to

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common/blob/master/features/analytics-gadget-templates/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.gadget.chart.template.feature/src/main/charts/line-chart/api.js#L116